# Why service data not reset in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As we work in angular  when we route from one url to another then controller data is Rest but service data is not reset.

Can someone please explain why its not reset. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Unclear to me. Can you elaborate _service not reset._?

Comment: edited my question

Comment: Services are singleton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Services are only instantiated once and every component depending on the service gets the same shared instance of it. Services are not "reset"/destroyed/torn down, they're permanent. Controllers are bound to scopes and come and go with the scope.

This in fact allows you to have a constant "backend" in the form of services which retain their state throughout the entire life cycle of the app, while controllers are temporary things bound to views which come and go as the GUI changes.

Comment: Thanks its very useful @deceze

Answer (score 1):

> Angular services are:
>
> Lazily instantiated – Angular only instantiates a service when an
>   application component depends on it.
>
> Singletons – Each component
>   dependent on a service gets a reference to the single instance
>   generated by the service factory.

You can read more about it in Angular's documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was a bit old but let me share on how I did to delete my data stored in service.

**service.ts**

```
data: any;//I made a storage variable like this so it will be undefined value by default

removeProductData() { 
  this.data= undefined;
}

//In your component just call this function `removeData()` wherever you want to delete your data.
```